# mywebsite.com/wp-admin it redirects to /wp-login.php and displays "File not found"

Tags: nginx, wordpress, docker, proxypass

On mywebsite.com, I have running docker container with wordpress.
I started it as

```
docker run -p 8000:80 --name docker-wordpress-nginx -d
```

and

```
docker ps
```

shows

```
0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp
```

and on my host I have nginx running with

```
server {
     listen   80;
...
server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
...
location / {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

I intentionally run docker container as 8000:80 becasue I have other things running on my host's port 80.
I logged into

```
mywebsite.com:8000/wp-admin/
```

and

```
http://mywebsite.com:8000/wp-admin/options-general.php
```

and changed Site Address (URL) from

```
http://mywebsite.com:8000
```

to

```
http://mywebsite.com
```

So, now, after I go here:

```
http://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/
```

I am redirected here:

```
http://mywebsite.com:8000/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

and after I log in, I am show this page:

```
http://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/
```

and i see it correctly. However, if I click on any link inside, like "Pages" link, I got blank page

```
File not Found
```

as web page content and address bar shows:

```
http://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page
```

Also, I tried to login to admin interface as

```
http://mywebsite.com:8000/wp-admin/
```

And after i provide user/password, the Main admin page was shown, and after clicking on any link, like before, I got

```
File not found.
```

I tried using

```
define('WP_HOME','http://mywebsite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://mywebsite.com');
```

in wp-config.php, but didn't help.

I really don't care whether I use

```
http://mywebsite.com:8000/wp-admin/
```

or

```
http://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/
```

as long as my admin interface works and I can use it without errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?